# SQL Server INNER JOIN according to condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to add `INNER JOIN` if and only if a variable of my T-SQL function isn't null and not empty like that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction]
    (@FrequencyFilter VARCHAR(10))    -- EXAMPLE '6;1;4'
    SELECT field1, field2, field3
    FROM Table1 AS T1
    JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T2.id = T1.t2Id

    IF @FrequencyFilter IS NULL OR EMPTY
       JOIN ((STRING_SPLIT(@FrequencyFilter , ';') AS FF ON FF.Value = T1.frequency
 
    WHERE T1.field4 = 'test'
```

I would like to only apply this join (none an outer), only if the frequency filter parameter isn't null and not empty

Comment: Use a table valued parameter instead of a delimited list of values and this becomes a simple solution.

Comment: You can't just dump an `IF` into a `SELECT` statement; logical flow operators can't be put into the middle of a statement. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: If it were a procedure I'd agree, @SeanLange , however, with functions table type parameters are more often a pain. Though how the OP is getting their delimited list does change that answer a little. If they are storing the value in the database, then it would make more sense to fix their design. If it's not, as it's from user input, then using a scalar value (not a delimited or table type) for the function's parameter would make more sense, and you `CROSS APPLY` to the function for each value in the table type parameter.

Comment: @Larnu you are right. I thought this was a procedure because when I glanced at the code there is no `RETURN`.

Comment: Yeah, the `FUNCTION`'s definition isn't at all valid, @SeanLange , so i did a bit of a double take initially . There's not a declaration of the return type, an `AS` or a `RETURN` clause.